# Building an scalable Spring MVC application

Tags: spring, rest, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, scalability

I'm trying to build a web application using Spring MVC.
I would be using it to server GUI as well as JSON content.

Has anybody deployed such a solution and can vouch for it that it works?
Any tips/tricks to keep in mind while designing  , deploying such a solution?

Comment: Did you looked here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135302/choosing-java-spring-as-a-scalable-server-side-framework-for-a-large-website 
Keep in mind that Spring or another framework by itself don't solve scalability problems. This is more infrastructure question. How much of scalability you think that you will need?

Comment: Seen the link before.I understand that by itself Spring is not gonna help.What i'm looking @ is are there any reference architectures/design which i can use or refer?Is there any live proven solution out there which has a proven working model?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how much *scalability* and *distribution* you need, you might have two general options:

- Bundle REST API and UI layer in one module. In this approach, you can directly use Spring MVC to access business/data layer and deliver the service.
- Deliver REST points in one module and UI in another. In this approach, you need to have a client in your "controller" to access the REST API and deliver the user interface.

In any case, I believe [Spring REST Data](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/rest) is a good project to look at especially if you need to have CRUD besides REST API in your application.

Comment: I have designed using option #2. But I intend to use the REST module(CRUD) and DB to be clustered. But i forsee some issues like Controller-REST api having long conversations can cause possible timeouts on the GUI since the turn around time for a response is not fixed from the CRUD layer. So i was looking for some tried and tested tips and tricks,design practices,best practices etc. I was thinking of leveraging some workflow engine for such long conversations but it would make the application heavyweight.

Comment: I believe you can find efforts that aim at _async_ REST calls and [JAX-RS 2.0](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/jax_rs_2_0_early) also supports it and it's definitely supported in Spring. The asynchronous REST clients will help better manage long running requests and create a more usable user experience.